# Get advanced indicators (oscillators) from binance with R

Tags: r, api, binance

I am using the Binance API via RStudio and I know how to extract basic info like bid/ask/open/close prices on Binance, but on advanced trading charts on binance I see more price indicators like EMA or RSI and I dont want to compute them from price log since they wont be 100% accurate. Is there a way to extract all indicators (oscillators) I see in advanced mode (from Binance API or another API)? Can't find any reference in Binance APIs.

Comment: Did you find a way to extract the indicators trought binance API ?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.